# System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute not working with NinjectDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have created an ASP.Net MVC Web Application and used NuGet to install Ninject version 2.2.1.4 and Ninject.MVC3 version 2.2.2.0.  This application uses forms authentication. I am having a problem getting Authorization to work...

This is my Application_Start method in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    // binding code goes here... 

    // Remove this dependency resolver and Authorisation will work...
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

And one of my actions in my controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

And the authenitcation section of my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

The problem is that un-authorized users go staright to the About view instead of being redirected to the LogOn.  I know that the problem is with the NinjectDependencyResolver becuase when I remove the "DependencyResolver.SetResolver..." line from the Application_Start un-authorized users are redirected.

I would be grateful for your help.

Regards, Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudn't set the DependencyResolver yourself.

Read the documentation https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application about how to set up an MVC application using this extension.